# Webcomponents based on <table>. Slot out of flow

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm try create data-grid with "web component" based on TABLE. I'm use slot in TBODY to append new items. But TR rows rendered out of TBODY. I don't understand this behavior.
[shadowDom disallow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) use TABLE and TR elements, possibly the reason is this, but using ***HTMLElement.appendChild()*** also doesn't work

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="module"> 
    class DataGrid extends HTMLElement {
      TEMPLATE_ID = '#data-grid';
      constructor() {
        super();
        this._records = [];
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._render(shadow);
      }

      _render(shadow){
        let tmpl = document.querySelector(this.TEMPLATE_ID);
        shadow.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
        //this.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true)); //
      }
    }

    customElements.define('data-grid', DataGrid);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <template id="data-grid">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>time</th>
          <th>voltage</th>
        <tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <slot></slot>
      <tbody>
    </table>
    </template>

    <data-grid>
      <!-- need replaced to component
<grid-row time="" voltage=""> 
 -->
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>123123123120</td>
        <td>12.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>123123133324</td>
        <td>12.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>123123122330</td>
        <td>12.2</td>
      </tr>
    </data-grid>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `<TR>` documentation on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

> ### Permitted parents
>
> `<table>` (only if the table has no child `<tbody>` element, and even
> then only after any `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, and `<thead>`
> elements); otherwise, the parent must be `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or
> `<tfoot>`

So

```html
<data-grid>
  <tr>
```

is **not** valid HTML

#### **move** (invalid) *lightDOM* to a `<table>` **inside** `<data-grid>`  *shadowDOM*

**note:** `attachShadow()` both **sets** and **returns** `this.shadowRoot` for free
No need to create your own `shadow` variable.

**psuedo code:**

```
const table = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("TABLE");
this.querySelectorAll("TR").forEach(table.appendChild);
```